# How to delete mutil indents in Emacs Haml mode?

Tags: ruby, emacs, haml

I installed haml-mode in my Emacs follow this article http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HamlMode

There is my code :

```
.row
         .a
           .b
             .c
```

I want to get

```
 .row
   .a
     .b
       .c
```

How to delele mulline intents, what is the shortcut ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing TAB several times while you're on the second line should do the job. in `haml-mode` changes to a lines indentation affect the indentation of the associated lines bellow it. More generally you can use [rectangular deletion](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) instead to delete the leading whitespaces from all 3 lines - <kbd>C-x r d</kbd> after you've selected a region.

Answer (score 0):

In Haml mode selection of the region below **.row** and pressing TAB once will fix the indent.